# Remove specific items from Object(,)

Tags: vb.net, epplus

I take data from Excel and store the data in a `Object(,)` variable, however I recognize that sometimes Excel could contain many empty last rows (sometimes not exactly empty but spaces inside cells) therefore have to exclude those items from `Object(,)`.

I found out to check first row and first cell whether it's either empty or contain spaces then remove that items from my `Object(,)`.

What I have done so far is:

```
Dim data As Object(,) = DirectCast(_excelWorksheet.SelectedRange(_excelWorksheet.Dimension.Start.Row, _excelWorksheet.Dimension.Start.Column, _excelWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row, _excelWorksheet.Dimension.End.Column).Value, Object(,))

'Check whether found empty rows items and remove them:

For row As Integer = 0 To data.GetUpperBound(0)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(data(row, 1).ToString.Trim) Then
        'how to remove that item from Object(,) ????
    End If
Next
```

But how do I remove it?

Comment: I think the best way is to create a New Object(,) so you can store the item if the last cell is not empty. Deleting from an object while iterating can cause out of bound exception

Comment: The only way to delete items from an array is to create a new array and fill it with the data you want to keep, then remove the old array. I suggest you follow Wai's suggestion and create a new one of the same size, then only add the non-empty items.